# How to use one controller view as a partial view for another controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, controller

Is it possible to use one controller view as a partial view of another controller view...

In my scenario my controller has an action method index and another controller having an action method index as follows.

First controller:

```
class TemplateItemsController < ApplicationController
def index
@template_items = TemplateItem.order('"TemplateGroup_id"')

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @template_items }
end
end
```

In the view, we display templateitems.

My second controller is as follows.

```
class EncounterController <Applicationcontoller
def index
end
end
```

And in the view I'm trying to access the first controller view in the second controller view as follows, but I got this error:

> <%= render :partial => 'template_items/index', :locals => {:index=>@template_items} %>

And:

> Missing partial template_items/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/murali/April22 ROR App/app/views" * "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-bootswatch-rails-helpers-2.3.1/app/views"

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The error clearly says that you don't have `_index` partial in `app/views/template_items`.

Comment: my problem is how to use one controller view as partial view for another controller view..

Comment: create the partial file in the folder and try you will get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Make a file named `template_items/_index.html.erb` and in it write:

```
<%= render :file => 'template_items/index.html.erb' %>
```

Now use:

```
<%= render :partial => 'template_items/index', :locals => {:index=>@template_items} %>
```

It should work.

Comment: Same error as above i mentioned,i saw the u r suggested post but it is not helpful for me

Comment: Missing partial /template_items/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/murali/April22 ROR App/app/views"
  * "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-bootswatch-rails-helpers-2.3.1/app/views"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, partials are saved as  `_index.html.erb`, and in your views/template_items it is `index.html.erb`, so it says that partial is missing.